# jQuery DropDown text/value show in next input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move selected option value or text to a next input field. However it never shows I even tried hard coding it.

**script**

```
function haz(elem){
    console.log($(elem).find('option:selected').val());
    $(elem).closest("input#hazard").text($(elem).find('option:selected').val());
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="hazard_header"><h3>Hazard</h3>
    <select id='haz_op' onchange="haz(this)">
        <option>--Select--</option>
        <option value="Airborne Particulates (Silica Dust)">Airborne Particulates (Silica Dust)</option>
        <option value="Asbestos">Asbestos</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <h3>or</h3>
</li>
<li class="hazard_input">
    <input type="text" name="hazard[]" id="hazard" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text here"/>
</li>
```

In the script part `console.log` executes fine I get the value of selected option however when I try to add it to `#hazard` input it never shows and I tried to just hard code a string and still nothing. ('Am I not selecting it correctly?')

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no need to navigate with respect to `$(elem)`. Just use  `$('#hazard')`. Also, `#hazard` is an `input` type element, so you should use `val()` instead of `text()`

**Update**

If you have multiple input elements, navigate like

```
$(elem).closest('li').nextAll('.hazard_input:first').find('[name="hazard[]"]').val($(elem).find('option:selected').val());
```

or assuming you have a parent `ul`, the easier

```
$(elem).closest('ul').find('[name="hazard[]"]').val($(elem).find('option:selected').val());
```

```js
function haz(elem){
   $(elem).closest('ul').find('[name="hazard[]"]').val($(elem).find('option:selected').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="hazard_header"><h3>Hazard</h3>
        <select id='haz_op' onchange="haz(this)">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option value="Airborne Particulates (Silica Dust)">Airborne Particulates (Silica Dust)</option>
            <option value="Asbestos">Asbestos</option>
        </select>
</li>
<li><h3>or</h3></li>
<li class="hazard_input">
<input type="text" name="hazard[]" id="hazard" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text here"/></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: reason i use elem to navigate as this is (item / row based) so there will be 1 to many hazards on the form.. and I don't want them ALL to change... This works but not correctly..( I  guess I just need to figure out how to navigate to the next hazard# element)

Comment: well, you do $('target-item).val($(elem).find('option:selected').val()); Also if you will be doing it in a iteration that have the same schema you can wrap it   into a common element and var e = $(elem);
e.closest('parent').find('target').val(e.find('option:selected').val())

Comment: Ammaer Thanks its perfect.

Comment: @theStudent, np. Btw, see my update for a slightly easier way